# Office365 Reporting for MailboxUsageDetail?

Tags: c#, office365, office365api, office365-restapi

I'm using REST API to get O365 MailboxUsageDetail report.

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn387059.aspx , the REST URI is:

https://reports.office365.com/ecp/reportingwebservice/reporting.svc/MailboxUsage[?ODATA options]

How come the URI is the same as the one for MailboxUsageSummary report?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn387058.aspx

I actually used 
https://reports.office365.com/ecp/reportingwebservice/reporting.svc/MailboxUsageDetail[?ODATA options]

to get the detail report before, and it worked. But for some reasons, now if I use it, it shows error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
```

Anyone knows what problem this is? Is it just O365 temparory issue and document has a typo? or something else?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The **MailboxUsageDetail** works well for me now. Is the issue fixed for you? I used the service request below:

```
https://reports.office365.com/ecp/reportingwebservice/reporting.svc/MailboxUsageDetail
```